# What power density could a cell phone battery achieve, and how?

Tags: batteries, electrochemistry

Current cell phones have batteries reaching about 3500mAh capacity, and I believe Lithium-Ion technology is rated at around 100Wh/kg (?)

Is there a theoretical limit to how much power could be stored in a reusable battery, and if so what are the limiting factors in terms of a 'realistic' limit i.e. something one could make and produce?

I've phrased this around a cell-phone battery to give the question some sort of boundaries. I suppose I am predominantly thinking about electrochemical power sources but if other options are within the realms of theoretical practicality that is fine.

Comment: When you say "battery" do you mean electrochemical cells, or any kind of energy storage?

Comment: there are many papers on this topic and the first thing you should do is read a quick intro which will allow you to fine tune your question ... do you want to consider rotating micro-gyros?  plutonium?  oxygen-breathing batteries? etc... for each technology there is a theoretical limit but you'll have to be a bit more precise about what counts as "nonsense"  :-(

Comment: @PaulYoung fair points. I've rephrased this around a specific form factor. Wild crazy theoretical upper limits are fine if the science supports them, but it's got an envelope in terms of mass, volume, etc now.

Comment: This article is short and good:  https://thebulletin.org/2009/01/the-limits-of-energy-storage-technology/

Comment: @PaulYoung Batteries, flywheels, wind-up springs, compressed air and capacitors are all ultimately limited by the strength of molecular bonds, so their capacities are within a couple of orders of magnitude.

Comment: @KeithMcClary - I agree.  But I do care whether my phone holds its charge for 10 minutes or for 16 hours ...  LOL